# Crosstab function and Dates PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I had to create a cross tab table from a Query where dates will be changed into column names. These order dates can be increase or decrease as per the dates passed in the query. The order date is in Unix format which is changed into normal format.

Query is following:

```
Select cd.cust_id
     , od.order_id
     , od.order_size
     , (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + od.order_date * INTERVAL '1 second')::Date As order_date
From consumer_details cd,
     consumer_order od,
Where cd.cust_id = od.cust_id
  And od.order_date Between 1469212200 And 1469212600
Order By od.order_id, od.order_date
```

Table as follows:

```
 cust_id   | order_id       |    order_size | order_date   
-----------|----------------|---------------|--------------
 210721008 | 0437756        |          4323 | 2016-07-22   
 210721008 | 0437756        |          4586 | 2016-09-24   
 210721019 | 10749881       |             0 | 2016-07-28   
 210721019 | 10749881       |             0 | 2016-07-28   
 210721033 | 13639          |       2286145 | 2016-09-06   
 210721033 | 13639          |       2300040 | 2016-10-03
```

Result will be:

```
 cust_id   | order_id       |    2016-07-22 |    2016-09-24 |    2016-07-28 |    2016-09-06 |    2016-10-03 
-----------|----------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------
 210721008 | 0437756        |          4323 |          4586 |               |               |               
 210721019 | 10749881       |               |               |             0 |               |               
 210721033 | 13639          |               |               |               |       2286145 |       2300040
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. While this is website for programmers to help one an other, we are not getting pay for this, so don't depend on SO for commercial work...

Comment: @Flummox I can understand this but this is required for me to understand whether we can do this kind of work only using Query or we need to have a function.

Comment: I think @Flummox means that [urgent begging is not acceptable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) when addressing volunteers, and he or she is quite right.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: I checked this link but the document did not tell about the dynamic handling of the dates as column in crosstab.